# ¿Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de columnas en un jtable?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

si no me equivoco en este codigo cree columnas de forma dinamica, he visto formas de cambiar el tamaño a las columnas y estoy utilizando este, pero las columnas se muestran del mismo tamaño(es decir al abrir el jframe, todas por ejemplo miden 200px) en la jtable. Sinceramente encontre el codigo en un video, asi que es la forma en la que crea lleno la tabla con una base de datos, pero no puedo cambiar el tamaño de las columnas.

También si hay una forma de agregar un scroll para cuando las columnas sean muy grandes, me ayudaria mucho.

```
public void LlenarTablaTrue(JTable TablaUbi) {
    DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
    TablaUbi.setModel(modeloT);

    modeloT.addColumn("ID");
    modeloT.addColumn("Ubicación");
    modeloT.addColumn("Descripción.");
    modeloT.addColumn("Estado");

    TablaUbi.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
    TablaUbi.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(27);
    TablaUbi.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
    TablaUbi.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
    TablaUbi.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(90);
    TablaUbi.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);

    Object[] columna = new Object[4];
    int numRegistros = ubicacionCRUD.listarTrue().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < numRegistros; i++) {
        columna[0] = ubicacionCRUD.listarTrue().get(i).getUbi_id();
        columna[1] = ubicacionCRUD.listarTrue().get(i).getUbi_nombre();
        columna[2] = ubicacionCRUD.listarTrue().get(i).getUbi_descripcion();
        String estado = "";
        estado = ubicacionCRUD.listarTrue().get(i).getUbi_estado().toString();
        if(estado.equals("true"))
            {
                estado = "Habilitado";
            }
            else 
            {
                estado = "Deshabilitado";
            }
        columna[3] = estado;

        modeloT.addRow(columna);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, habia agregado eso por que buscando decia que para que funcionara debia estar ahí, asi que con el o sin el no funciona.

Comment: Quita el auto-resize del código y fija tu las dimensiones de cada columna